# Why does an odd number price look smaller than an even number price?

Tags: price-range, prices

Whenever I go to a fast food restaurant or a store, I noticed that the product prices end with a 9 rather than a 0.

Please see the example below. Even though the difference is just 1 pence,  people perceive £2.99 as a much smaller number than £3.00. That is because the price ends in 99.

[image]

Now, please take a look at the second example below. Even though **the price is not ending with "99"**, people still perceive it as cheaper. What is the reason behind this?
[image]

Comment: 9 doesn't look smaller than 0, but 2 looks smaller than 3....

Comment: My wife would tell you that the burger costs only 2 pounds.

Comment: Is it just me, or does the burger on the left *look* better?

Comment: This often leads to me remembering a higher than actual price. I map 2.99 to 3 when reading it. And then when recalling it, I remember it as 3.99 and round it to 4.

Comment: Now I'm starting to see things that are 2.97

Comment: At Thrift Stores in the US (called Charity Shops in UK) prices are often marked $4.04, $11.11 and so on. I am guessing that this is some kind of heuristic or checksum for validating that: 1) prices have not been modified 2) all the math adds up.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: And then, when you go to the store the next time and see it's only 2.99, you are happy about the low price (or even the discount) and immediately decide to buy, right? ;)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper either way, if you go in, you are pretty likely to buy. The only thing that changes is how you *feel* about it later. Most of the effort of Marketing is just to **get you in there** in the first place. After that, the effort required for you to leave and find another place to purchase makes it more worthwhile to buy, even if the price is not optimal. How much is your time worth? (lazy eight) (Shh! you'll ruin the story)

Comment: Some say the reason for this is we focus on the first figure first and perceive it to be of much lower value but on the other hand lets suppose you bought something for 995 rupees or even 980 yens and if someone asked you how much did it cost you tend to tell them its almost 1000 yens. Weird human psychology isn't it?

Comment: [related](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2359/the-origin-of-99-cents)

Comment: @the_lotus That's probably a storekeeping thing.  I've worked for stores that, for example, mark products which have been discontinued with a price like XX.97, regular products get XX.99, products currently on sale get XX.96 (as compared to YY.99 "regular price")  I'm not sure how this is a significant advantage to management, since I was just a labour monkey myself, but they seemed to think of it as "standard practice."  (The "on sale" thing could've been a red flag for cashiers if a customer came up complaining a product was "on sale" for XX.99 instead of YY.99, I suppose.)

Comment: @Steve-O there's also "we're always cheaper than our rival for the same product" 99 times out of 100 it's a matter of charging £x.97 when the rival charges £x.99.

Comment: That is because marketing is like politics, religions, media and everything else you know (including science): there are those who study the psychology of the mass and they use it to reach their goals.

Comment: There's an apocryphal story that the practice originated before sales tax when having an even amount for a cost would allow a cashier to "complete" a transaction without opening the til. Requiring change to be tendered supposedly reduced the likelihood of embezzlement.

Comment: This seems like a marketing question and not a UX question. UX is about making a presentation/interface best meet the needs and understanding of the user, not about how to trick them in order to increase profit.

Comment: @R..: "UX is about making a presentation/interface best meet the needs and understanding of the user" - in practice, the purpose of UX (at least on this site) seems to be a bit more general, namely about making a presentation/interface best achieve a particular reaction of a user. This is usually in some way directly beneficial for the user, but admittedly, purposes such as "giving the user a good feeling while buying something overpriced" fall within that realm, as well.

Comment: I think this should not be consider as duplicate. Reason is "Urbycoz" question especially focused on price with "99" ending (https://tinyurl.com/lq3qak), Where as question here is totally different saying "if the price which don't end with "99" is also perceived by people as lesser amount". But if admin feel this is duplicate let respect the decision and make as duplicate.

Comment: It's like, one less, ya know? (paraphrase from *This Is Spinal Tap*)

Answer (score 76):

Ending a price in .99 is based on the theory that, **because we read from left to right, the first digit of the price resonates with us the most.**

That's why someone is more likely to buy a product for $2.99 than the same one for $3. The item that starts with a 2 just seems like a better deal than the one that starts with 3.

Source: [Why Do Most Prices End in .99?](http://www.livescience.com/33045-why-do-most-prices-end-in-99-cents-.html)

Here's a great article about pricing cues.

> Another common pricing cue is using a 9 at the end of a price to
>   denote a bargain. In fact, this pricing tactic is so common, you’d
>   think customers would ignore it. Think again. Response to this pricing
>   cue is remarkable. You’d generally expect demand for an item to go
>   down as the price goes up. Yet in our study involving the women’s
>   clothing catalog, we were able to increase demand by a third by
>   raising the price of a dress from $34 to $39. By comparison, changing
>   the price from $34 to $44 yielded no difference in demand.

Source: [Mind Your Pricing Cues](https://hbr.org/2003/09/mind-your-pricing-cues)

**Edit**

Provided link to original article. Thanks, DPS.

**Edit two**

Talking about the second example, the above theory is still valid. When someone sees 79, the '7' is smaller than '8' when someone sees 80.

Comment: A link to your bolded text would have been a lot helpful http://www.livescience.com/33045-why-do-most-prices-end-in-99-cents-.html  Ending a price in .99 is based on the theory that, **because we read from left to right, the first digit of the price resonates with us the most**, Hibbett explained. That's why shoppers are more likely to buy a product for $4.99 than an identical one for $5 the item that starts with a 4 just seems like a better deal than the one that starts with 5.

Comment: I'm confused by the phrase "because we read from left to right, the first digit of the price resonates with us the most". Whatever direction we read in there would be a first digit.

Comment: What it means is that we remember the first thing we see more than what comes after. So the 2 of 2,99 is a better digit to remember than the 3 of 3,00 because people think 2 is better(cheaper) than 3.

Comment: My issue is that the clause "because we read from left to right" in the article is unnecessary. Whichever direction we read and write text in, we would read the first digit first. Presumably the effect also occurs for prices spoken aloud?

Comment: What you wrote at the beginning does not match with the passage you cited. Particularly, why demand increased at $39 compared to that at $34, and why $34 vs $44 has no effect is not explained, and they actually contradict your whole point.

Comment: @sawa It's a reference to a larger study about pricing in general for further reading.

Comment: Your answer may be correct, but is not coherent, and as an answer to the question given, it is actually not at all clear. Sometimes, adding unnecessary things can ruin an otherwise good answer.

Comment: @aPaulT Reading from left to right seems important when talking specifically about prices like 2.99 vs 3.00, since the first digit is then 2 vs 3 (2 is lower) rather than 9 vs 0 (9 is higher, so the price may be perceived as being *worse*, even though it's lower), unless we're also assuming that the number is switched around if we change the direction we read from (i.e. 2.99 reading ltr is identical to 99.2 reading rtl). I don't know if that's actually the case for languages that are written from right to left.

Comment: If you are adding a column of prices, then you read each price right to left so you can carry 10s to the next column. If the effect is not seen in such cases, then it does matter which direction the price is read.

Comment: @aPaulT But, we *always* **speak** from left to right.

Comment: @nocomprende Almost always:  _$1_

Comment: What's important is not direction left-to-right or right-to-left, but rather whether numbers are read most-significant digit to least-significant digit or vice versa; English tends toward the former pattern outside of some archaic constructs, e.g. "Four-and-twenty blackbirds".

Comment: I suspect (but haven't dug for any confirmation) that the effect is stronger when buying several items. Wandering around a shop and picking items that are £2.99, £5.99 and £1.99 will often be perceived / mentally-added-together as £2-odd + £5-odd + £1-odd for a total of £8-something instead of a shade under £10. You decide to buy based on your rough approximation and either don't notice, or don't care that you were "a bit out" when you finally get to the till.

Comment: @nocomprende actually, in other languages, people would say "nine and twenty" for twenty nine (German, Dutch...). I wonder if consumers speaking those languages behave differently? I still see pricing of this form in Germany and Netherlands though, so seems not.

Comment: @Dhara: I doubt it. Prices such as €0.99, €1.99, €19.99, €199.99 are all very common in Germany. See my [other comment here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/107900#comment174325_107902) where I suggest reading/writing direction is completely irrelevant for this effect.

Comment: @Dhara So, we can all agree: regardless of reading direction, how numbers are written or read, or any other consideration, it is abundantly clear that *either the first or the last digit* influences price perception in some mysterious and inexplicable way. I think we can publish those results, don't you? It has been proven to everyone's satisfaction, especially the ones setting prices, who would do otherwise if it was ineffective.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: I am from Italy and I live in Germany. I see prices ending in .99 from time to time, but I do not think they are the majority. Here are prices taken from a bill from a local shop: 2.49, 1.69, 1,09, 4,99, 4.99, 2.99, 1.99, 3.79, 1.29, 1.25. Prices ending in .99 are less than half, but most end in 9. This I find already very disturbing. I read 4.99 as 5, 1.99 as 2, and so on. The shop just causes me the extra effort to do the rounding in my mind and it feels like they are cheating.

Comment: I wonder how much the effect is reinforced by the cents digits often being printed in a smaller font size than the whole numbers.

Comment: If You read the second article you'll see that it shows an increase of sales when increasing the price from x.00 to x.99. So your given explanation is refuted by your own sources. The article itself is very interesting though.

Comment: @sawa increasing the price from $34 - $39 doesn't conflict in that the most significant digit hasn't changed (as opposed to 34 - 44). But what it does mean is that this technique has now been used for so long that it (at least in the dollar amount) has taken on a new form of signalling. I find it a fascinating extra bit of info.

Answer (score 22):

## tl;dr

Taking your example:

> We (the fast food chain) found that customers don't want to spend $3 on our hamburger.
>   Customers are willing to pay somewhere in the $2 range.
>   Our customers focus on dollars not cents.
>   So, anything less than $2.99 is throwing cents away.
>   The board gets mad when we throw money away.

## Pricing is complex, Humans are lazy

I might almost go so far as to say we're dumb — but that's too far. Cognitively speaking, we look for quick, simplistic answers. In the case of pricing, consumers make glancing assessments based on prices we've encountered in the past. This assessment can psychologically override the actual value of the item. This is especially true for *lower* priced items, whatever that threshold might be.

## Psychological Pricing Theory

The complexity of minute changes in price have been studied extensively and generally fall under the label of [Psychological Pricing Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_pricing). Read that page on Wikipedia for a lot of detail and some historical findings.

One key point, is they way consumers "round" the price. *It's a higher level issue than simply left-to-right reading.* It has to do with orders of importance. Specifically, the dollars are psychologically more important than the change. As quoted in the Wiki article:

> **Consumers ignore the least significant digits rather than do the proper rounding.** Even though the cents are seen and not totally ignored, they may subconsciously be partially ignored.

Fast Company wrote an article, [*The Psychology Behind the Sweet Spots of Pricing*](https://www.fastcompany.com/1826172/psychology-behind-sweet-spots-pricing), that speaks to a related concept.

> According to a study conducted by Kenneth J. Wisniewski from the University of Chicago, when the price of margarine dropped from 89 cents to 71 cents at a local grocery chain, sales improved by 65%. But when the price fell two cents more to 69 cents, sales jumped by an astounding 222%!

FastCo also proposed that the digital age may have introduced new sweet spots, but this has not been proven out yet.

> Has $5.00 usurped $4.99 as a sweeter spot for luring customers?

Historically, pricing format has also been used as a means of record keeping, odd as that may sound today. Some retailers, even up to my experience in e-comm 10 years ago, used one format for regular prices and another for sale prices. Picking up on the theory that .99 performs better with price-sensitive buyers, many companies made that their sale standard. This has a compound effect: **Consumers are subsequently trained to recognize 99 as the sale number.**

## In practice

Working in the e-comm world for several years, I had the opportunity to evaluate some very interesting pricing studies. The exact numbers varied, but the common factor in on-line buying habits was that **anything after the dollars was effectively ignored.**

I reviewed tests run at .00, .50, .95, .97, and .99 (just off the top of my head). Once the priced moved up or down a dollar, the cents had minimal impact on sales. IOW, asking $29.50 for an item rather than $29.99 just lost the seller 49 cents. Sell 10-20,000 units and you start to feel the spare change.

In the data I reviewed, the 99 effect was not as dramatic as discount retailers have seen. I worked primarily with mid-range and some high-end markets. Interestingly, in these markets, we found evidence that the price brackets had a bigger impact than the 9s. For example, pricing an item anywhere between $40-49 made very little difference. As soon as that item moved into the $50-75 bracket, volume would decrease.

For mid-range markets, these brackets tended to brake down as follows:

- 5-9.99
- 10-19.99
- 20-29.99
- 30-39.99
- 40-49.99
- 50-75.00*
- 76-99.99
- 100-125.00*
- 126-149.99
- 150-175.00*

* Those zeros aren't accidental. At these points, consumers responded best when the high point in the bracket stuck to the even dollar amount. In my findings the 99.99 and 149.99 points showed that it wasn't simply a matter of crossing some imaginary line. Some colleagues suggested that 25 and 75 became *magic* numbers after the 100 mark. YMMV ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

**Effectively, it appeared that in mid-range price points consumers were mentally focused on the tens rather than the ones or cents.** Price sensitivity up to a given bracket's `_9.99` was fairly light. Crossing into the next bracket triggers a spike in that sensitivity and volume was disproportionately impacted.

## Reverse psychology

One side-effect worth noting: I have also seen an inverse effect to the "deal shopping" mentality. Consumers of high-end items (jewelry, haute couture, fine decor and furniture, etc) aren't supposed to care about price. That's part of the status of owning those items. In those markets, I have seen evidence that there is a sort of branding effect that happens when the price is set with .00, no cents notation at all, and even no $.

For example, a dress from a Parisian high-fashion designer valued at about $4,600.00 could be priced according to any of the following formats:

1. > $4,599.99
2. > $4,599.00
3. > $4,600
4. > 4,600

From what I've seen in tests between $200.00-599.99, #4 would be the winning option. To a status- or craftsmanship-conscious buyer, my hypothesis is that this format shows confidence in one's product and an unwillingness to compromise. #1 in particular implies a sales rather than craft focus and may turn this consumer away.

Comment: Should the categories following the starred ones be 75.01-99.99, 125.01-149.99, etc.?

Comment: @supercat That's what my footnote was referencing. In the numbers I saw, going 1 cent over 75 was the same as jumping to 76. Unfortunately, pricing strategy doesn't follow a linear curve, even within the same product line.

Comment: At present, your table doesn't say whether prices in the range 75.01-75.99 are treated the same as those 76.00 and up or 74.99 and down.  If 75.01 is the same as 76.00, then the range you list as 76-99.99 should instead be 75.01-99.99, should it not?

Comment: @supercat do with the table as you wish. These are the price brackets that repeatedly surfaced as worthy of experimentation. There were gaps that were not -- 75.01-75.99 was one of those gaps. At higher price points, gaps can be wider, but my "evidence" there is spottier.

Comment: If no experiments were conducted with prices in the range $75.01-$75.99, but $76 yielded results similar to all other prices that were tested up to $99.99, the footnote should acknowledge the gap.  As it is, it's unclear whether the tipping point is $75.01, $76.00, or somewhere between.

Comment: @supercat sorry for the confusion. This was simply illustrative of how price strategy *can* shape up. Experiments were conducted in the gaps. In the case of a $75 item, +1 cent increments consistently performed poorly compared to prices below that threshold. It's a strange phenomenon and worthy of re-testing in any new market/brand. Again, included here simply for illustration of how pricing strategy isn't always a simple linear equation.

Comment: I expanded on the "gaps" in the answer. Hopefully, this helps avoid future confusion

Comment: According to your last point about price without cent notation, can it be concluded that for products aim specifically at **(evoking) customer's emotion**, the price should show the confidence of the seller? Would this be a drawback for mid-range market (less than $100)?

Comment: @Ooker we're well into the realm of speculation now, but is a different psychological strategy. A *different* emotion, perhaps.

Comment: @plainclothes do you have any relevant keyword that doesn't appear in this discussion so that I can reach the right research quicker?

Comment: @Ooker "psychological pricing theory/strategy" is the big one. Start with that Wikipedia article and you could disappear into a rabbit hole for days.

Answer (score 17):

The main reason to end a price for product in .9 or .99 is **human psychology**.

Research has proved that "Consumers perceive such prices lower than they actually are. So that additional 1 pence seems much more valuable to a consumer than it actually is."

Consumers tend to "round down" that value to the nearest dollar. E.g., $9.99 would be rounded down to $9 instead of up to $10. So the perception is actually getting the product at $1 less, instead of getting it at $0.01 less.

This is where that additional one pence would make a great difference (in consumers mind and not in actual value).

You can find a lot of research on the internet under "psychological pricing". You can start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_pricing.

Comment: I also agree to the point @NGAFD mentioned. People read from left to right. So the first digit that brain register for the price $2.99 is "2". So the value registered with brain is "2" and not "3" (even if the value is closer to 3)

Comment: Not all languages read left-to-right.

Comment: @JDługosz still even for languages where it's read right to left (arabic for example), you still read a price 4,99 and not 99,4

Comment: In Aribic , where our numbers *come from*, they still put the most significant digit on the left.  But to them that’s little endian — left is *last*.

Comment: @JDługosz Agreed and a very valid point! However the human psychology does not change whether you read it left to right or right to left. Brain would still register the first digit or character

Comment: The **first** is 9 cents, if reading rtl.  You are supposing that ltr is somehow more innate and the other languages are backwards?

Comment: It is not innate with respect to other languages. Example: For me, English is third or fourth language. But when i read a sentence in English i would read it left to right. Arabic, I would read right to left. It is just the matter of how you read a particular language. But the VALUE registered would be 4.99 and not 99.4!

Comment: @AdityaDurgude I think the point he's trying to make is that if we see 4.99 and assuming the Arab's had these numbers first (which is actually wrong, it's the Indian's that just didn't get the credit for this one), they may read 4.99 from right to left. Because there's no innate starting digit for a number. There's no reason to believe you couldn't have a language where you write 4.99 and read it 9 cents + 90 cents  + point + 4. I'm not sure if this is the case in arabic or any other language. But ordering from most to least significant digit is arbitrary.

Comment: Probably @JDlugosz's case does hold water. For example 54 in Deutsche (German) is read as "vierundfünfzig" that is "4 and 50" (here the sentence is read from left to right). Need to check about it. But to answer the question, in English language it is because reading from left to right.

Comment: I always round it up, but it doesn't help. I see the `2.99` burger, round it up to `3` and wonder if it is a good deal. And then I think "Well, I can't decide, it is kind of a tie. But I already rounded up the price, so I'm actually not paying as much as I was calculating with, so I should just buy it". And being aware of it doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: @JDługosz: Written/spoken direction is irrelevant. More significant digits remain more significant for the total price, irrespective of the order in which they are written or read out aloud. The trick is to confuse people about the distance to the next higher/lower number by tempting them to assign a greater relative importance to a given digit than it has.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Yes, I don't always get what I am saying either. But regardless of whether we recall where we bought something, we *always* pay for it where we found it. So you could look at the receipt if you want to find it again, without looking all over. And that is why the used car places around here say "Buy Here, Pay Here" with such large signs. What else would anyone do? But they make it so easy that people come in and buy! Imagine how much we would all buy if they just made the payment process simpler? And we could go back again and again, if we can figure out where we went last time.

Comment: Im surprised no one has mentioned Apple's app store. They have done their own studies and, it's the reason (most of) their apps are 0.99 instead of 1.00. There was a significant decline in the number of purchases once they met that next threshold.

Comment: @nocomprende: Many businesses have charity collection jars or "give/take a penny" bowls.  Perhaps the clerks take the penny and throw it in one of the jars/bowls, or maybe they just throw the extra pennies in their pocket.  My point was that I've seen businesses which will treat a posted tax-inclusive price of $1.99 as $2.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what appears to almost universally believed, the original reason for this practice was to prevent fraud. It was to keep the customer at the counter until the transaction was completed, in the days when the sales docket and the money tendered were whisked overhead in a basket to a cashier. By making sure there would always be change to give back to the customer, the opportunities for sales assistants to perpetrate frauds were reduced. They had to write e correct amount on the docket, tender at least that much money, wait for the cashier to check it, wait for the correct change to be returned, and return the change to the customer. So the customer had an interest in waiting for the entire internal transaction to complete correctly.

Comment: Sounds interesting - do you have any references for this?

Comment: Overhead baskets? I think you have watched the movie *Brazil* too many times : )

Comment: @O.R.Mapper In fact my grandfather used to run a  furniture store with them, and I may have got it from him.

Comment: @nocomprende Neither seen it nor heard of it, but I'm old enough to remember them. Saw some last week in a W.C. Fields movie.

Comment: Well, then this is probably the correct answer. Good luck, mate!

Answer (score 0):

For me, this goes back to our infancy where counting numbers was something hard and fun when done right. So there's a bit of excitement into the "almost promoted" number.

It's the first time we start dealing with the main number system used today, the 10 base system and the numbers start changing into something different, a double digit one. So from the teacher, we get a reward for getting to another digit every time.

For no confusion let's call it the **Promotion factor**

When our brain interprets the number there's a cognitive *tick* to the fact that the number is almost another number.

So what I see is that the customer get's this subliminal message that says "Yes! you counted well!" which taps to our childhood memories.

And this triggers being the promotion to another number **just .01 away**

In the end, when the time of decision comes to mind there's the embedded information of the **promotion factor** and that renders more *excitement* to the decision of taking the .99 ( which alleviates some of the need to get out of the anxiousness of choice-making )

Let's say we all know a better-looking package attracts more clients and this one is in your **cognitive process**.

As an example of this factor think of how more exciting is when a sports team wins by a close number rather than when it's far away. Maybe you could also measure with a set of length varied strips on a paper, randomly arranged and linearly arranged (like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 centimeters strips) and ask someone which seems more dramatic and one will mostly look more dramatic than the other in comparison.

This shows how information can too yield emotion by itself and when this emotion is something that says we counted well then it's assuring towards the anxiousness of having to choose between two good options.

Comment: "Tonight I'm gonna party like it's 1999."

Comment: Interesting idea. How does this create the impression that the price is lower than it really is?

Comment: @plainclothes thanks for the feedback, the idea was not expressed just my piece of mind

Comment: As stated in your answer, it would imply that the opposite of the OP's question is true. I suspect that's not what you meant. Could you expand on the childhood experience position to explore why consumers perceive a 1 cent reduction to be much greater than it is?

Comment: @plainclothes The promotion factor is when the number is almost a promoted one